# Potential Bug: See who voted last?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, votes

I replied to a question on SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/5334/how-to-create-a-torrent-and-share-with-others). The problem came in when I went back to the SuperUser home page and looked at the question, it showed an update by someone else, however apart from voting the question had not changed at all. Is this a caching delay maybe?

*(I am unable to post screenshots from work since all free hosting sites are blocked, but will upload later today)*

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a caching problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been caching the homepage for almost a year now. Wait 60 seconds..